# Exclude 0 Values from the query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get the final grades of the students of the place where I work.

The query works great except that if there's a 0 value, it includes it, and this cannot happen. How can I exclude 0 from my query, if I'm not mistaken, the 0 excluded must be from the AVG in the query.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
gbc.StudentID as [Student ID],
per.FirstName + ' ' + per.MiddleName + ' ' + per.LastName as [Student Name], 
gbc.ClassID as [Class ID],
cls.Name as [Class Name],
ROUND(SUM(gbc.weightedgrade),0) as [Final Grade]
FROM (SELECT 
    gg.ClassID, 
    gg.StudentID, 
    ga.AssessmentId, 
    ga.Title , 
    AVG(gg.ReceivedPoints * ga.Weight / 100.0) as weightedgrade
FROM GbkAssessments as ga INNER JOIN GbkGrades as gg ON ga.AssessmentID = gg.AssessmentID AND ga.ClassID = gg.ClassID 
JOIN Classes as cls on ga.classID = cls.classID JOIN GbkSummary as gbs on ga.classID = gbs.classID
WHERE gg.StudentID = 1201417 and cls.YearID = 251 and gbs.TermID = 1
GROUP BY gg.StudentID, gg.ClassID, ga.AssessmentId, ga.Title) as gbc JOIN Classes as cls on gbc.classID = cls.classID 
join Person as Per on Per.PersonID = gbc.StudentID join Person_Student as PS on Per.PersonID = PS.StudentID 
GROUP BY gbc.StudentID, gbc.ClassID, cls.Name, per.FirstName, per.LastName, per.MiddleName
ORDER BY gbc.ClassID ASC
```

My query includes the 0's  from some assessments that are present but don't have a value yet, example a quiz that hasn't been applied, a classwork that hasn't been checked.

How can I remove those values from being taken on account? Is there an AVGIFNOTNULL or something like that?

Comment: AVG ignores null values. Try to add an additional condition ` AND gg.ReceivedPoints * ga.Weight <> 0` in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       AVG (CASE WHEN Value <> 0 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)

        SELECT 
        gbc.StudentID as [Student ID],
        per.FirstName + ' ' + per.MiddleName + ' ' + per.LastName as [Student Name], 
        gbc.ClassID as [Class ID],
        cls.Name as [Class Name],
        CASE WHEN gbc.weightedgrade IS NOT NULL THEN ROUND(SUM(gbc.weightedgrade),0) ELSE NULL END as [Final Grade]
        FROM (SELECT 
            gg.ClassID, 
            gg.StudentID, 
            ga.AssessmentId, 
            ga.Title , 
            CASE WHEN gg.ReceivedPoints IS NOT NULL AND ga.Weight IS NOT NULL  
              THEN
                 AVG(gg.ReceivedPoints * ga.Weight / 100.0) 
                ELSE NULL 
              END as weightedgrade
        FROM GbkAssessments as ga INNER JOIN GbkGrades as gg ON ga.AssessmentID = gg.AssessmentID AND ga.ClassID = gg.ClassID 
        JOIN Classes as cls on ga.classID = cls.classID JOIN GbkSummary as gbs on ga.classID = gbs.classID
        WHERE gg.StudentID = 1201417 and cls.YearID = 251 and gbs.TermID = 1
        GROUP BY gg.StudentID, gg.ClassID, ga.AssessmentId, ga.Title) as gbc JOIN Classes as cls on gbc.classID = cls.classID 
        join Person as Per on Per.PersonID = gbc.StudentID join Person_Student as PS on Per.PersonID = PS.StudentID 
        GROUP BY gbc.StudentID, gbc.ClassID, cls.Name, per.FirstName, per.LastName, per.MiddleName
        ORDER BY gbc.ClassID ASC
```

Comment: Where ever your taking avg and you want to exclude any zeros you can use Case statement there, hope this will help

Comment: Can you put this case in my query so i can understand better what you're trying to say?

Comment: Im not sure exactly what fields can be null in your data but im sure from this code you'll have some idea anything that can be null and can effect your calculation replace it with null.

Comment: Sorry I meant anything that can be zero and effect your calculations replace it with null

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

add this to where

```
and AVG(gg.ReceivedPoints * ga.Weight / 100.0) <>0
```