# MySQL Query to average 3 columns and exclude 0's?

Tags: mysql

This is obviously wrong, but what would be the correct way to average the SUM of 3 columns and exclude the 0's?

```
SELECT ( 
    AVG(NULLIF(`dices`.`Die1`,0)) + 
    AVG(NULLIF(`dices`.`Die2`,0)) + 
    AVG(NULLIF(`dices`.`Die3`,0)) 
) /3  as avgAllDice 
FROM (
    SELECT `Die1`,`Die2`,`Die3` FROM `GameLog` 
    WHERE PlayerId = "12345"
) dices
```

Thanks.

Comment: See Normalisation .

Comment: What's the point of the subquery?

Comment: `(Die1 + Die2 + Die3) / ((Die1 <> 0) + (Die2 <> 0) + (Die3 <> 0))`

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19169994/7112888

Answer (score 0):

If I was keeping the inline view query (it's not clear why it's needed). I'd probably do something like this:

```
SELECT AVG( NULLIF( CASE d.i
                    WHEN 1 THEN dices.`Die1`
                    WHEN 2 THEN dices.`Die2` 
                    WHEN 3 THEN dices.`Die3`
                    END
            ,0)
       ) AS `avgAllDice`
  FROM ( SELECT gl.`Die1`
              , gl.`Die2`
              , gl.`Die3`
           FROM `GameLog` gl 
          WHERE gl.playerId = '12345'
       ) dices
 CROSS
  JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 ) d
```

The trick is the cross join operation, giving me three rows for each row returned from dices, and an expression that picks out values of `Die1`, `Die2` and `Die3` on each of three rows, respectively.

To exclude values of 0, we replace 0 with with NULL (since AVG doesn't include NULL values.)

Now with all of the non-zero `DieN` values stacked into a single column, we can just use the AVG function.

---

Another way to do it would be to get the numerator and denominator for each of `Die1`, `Die2`, `Die3`.... and then total up the numerators, total up the denominators, and then divide the total numerator by the total denominator.

This will should give an equivalent result.

```
SELECT ( IFNULL(t.n_die1,0) + IFNULL(t.n_die2,0) + IFNULL(t.n_die3,0) )
     / (        t.d_die1    +        t.d_die2    +        t.d_die3    )
       AS avgAllDice 
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(  NULLIF(gl.die1,0))   AS n_die1
              , COUNT(NULLIF(gl.die1,0))   AS d_die1
              , SUM(  NULLIF(gl.die2,0))   AS n_die2
              , COUNT(NULLIF(gl.die2,0))   AS d_die2
              , SUM(  NULLIF(gl.die3,0))   AS n_die3
              , COUNT(NULLIF(gl.die3,0))   AS d_die3
           FROM `GameLog` gl
          WHERE gl.playerid = '12345'
       ) t
```

(I didn't work out what gets returned in the edge and corner cases... no matching rows in `GameLog`, all values of `Die1`, `Die2` and `Die3` are zero, etc., for either query. The results might be slightly different, returning a zero instead of NULL, divide by zero edge case, etc.)

**FOLLOWUP**

I ran a quick test of both queries.

```
CREATE DATABASE d20170228 ;
USE d20170228 ; 
CREATE TABLE GameLog
( playerid VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '12345'
, die1 TINYINT
, die2 TINYINT
, die3 TINYINT
);
INSERT INTO GameLog (die1,die2,die3)
VALUES (3,0,0),(2,1,0),(4,3,3),(3,3,3),(0,0,0),(4,4,4),(5,4,0),(0,0,2)  
;
SELECT (3+2+1+4+3+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+5+4+2)/15  AS manual_avg
```

manual_avg is coming out 3.2.

Both queries are also returning 3.2

Comment: EXCELLENT! Thank you. Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Bubba:  added another way to do it, which may perform better for large sets. This still has an inline view (intermediate result materialized as a derived table), but since the view query returns only a single row, it's gonna be a really small derived table.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure why there is another SELECT either. It could probably be cleaned up better. But it works. So Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there could be up to 30,000 dice values to average.

Comment: For large sets, we'd expect the second pattern to perform better, since it avoids the cross join, potentially tripling the number of rows in an intermediate set. The second approach cruises through the GameLog table one time, and collapses that down into a single row. And the outer query doing arithmetic on a single row doesn't move the needle, in terms of performance.

Comment: The second code returns a different result. 3.5068 regardless of how many rows/dice I include. The first one is more accurate.

Comment: @Bubba. Hmm.  I didn't test it, just desk checked. That's got the expression (NULLIF function) to return NULL in place of zero. We know the SUM and COUNT handle NULL values just fine. The `n_` aliases are on the numerator, the `d_` aliases on the denominators. The expression in the outer query looks right to me `( n_ + n_ + n_ ) / ( d_ + d_ + d_ )`   I will have to test to see what's going on.  (My last edit to the answer added the `avgAllDice` alias to the expression returned by the outer query... maybe there was something garfed when you copied it and I already fixed, after you copied it...

Comment: I noticed the edit and have tested the latest version.

Comment: I used this data set to test:

6 0 0
1 4 0
1 3 0
6 1 1
3 1 6
5 0 0
3 5 0
1 0 0
1 0 0
1 2 0
1 3 6
4 0 0
3 1 0
4 1 4
2 3 1
4 2 4
5 6 5
4 3 3
6 4 0
5 2 6
2 4 5
5 4 3
2 5 1
1 3 0
6 6 1
4 2 3
2 2 3
5 1 3
3 4 2
2 2 5
5 4 2
2 1 4
3 6 6
4 3 4
3 5 6
5 3 2
5 3 5
6 6 2
4 1 3
4 6 2
3 3 1
2 5 4
5 4 3
6 2 5
3 6 6

Comment: I tested both queries with that data set. Both queries returning 3.4492. Also `SELECT ( 6+0+0+1+4+0+1+3+0+6+1+1+3+1+6+5+0+0+3+5+0+1+0+0+1+0+0+1+2+0+1+3+6+4+0+0+3+1+0+4+1+4+2+3+1+4+2+4+5+6+5+4+3+3+6+4+0+5+2+6+2+4+5+5+4+3+2+5+1+1+3+0+6+6+1+4+2+3+2+2+3+5+1+3+3+4+2+2+2+5+5+4+2+2+1+4+3+6+6+4+3+4+3+5+6+5+3+2+5+3+5+6+6+2+4+1+3+4+6+2+3+3+1+2+5+4+5+4+3+6+2+5+3+6+6 ) / 118`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate zeroes and NULLs, you can simply `SELECT` from the filtered master set multiple times, doing a `UNION ALL` on the results, then averaging against that.

```
SELECT AVG(`allDice`.`DieResult`)
FROM (
    SELECT `Die1` AS `DieResult` FROM `GameLog` WHERE COALESCE(`Die1`, 0) <> 0 AND PlayerId = '12345'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `Die2` FROM `GameLog` WHERE COALESCE(`Die2`, 0) <> 0 AND PlayerId = '12345'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `Die3` FROM `GameLog` WHERE COALESCE(`Die3`, 0) <> 0 AND PlayerId = '12345'
) AS `allDice`
```

There's no need to overthink this one, it's not too difficult a problem